# USB problems in dual booting Linux Mint and Windows 7

Tags: usb, dual-boot, mouse

After I installed Mint from a live USB, I immediately ran into USB problems. First problem was that when I switched from linux to windows, my mouse and keyboard would get disabled and I would have to do a hard reset just to be able to to use windows, everytime.

I did some digging and found out that I should set Intel xHCI to disabled. I did and it solved my problem.

Until recently, where my mouse and only my mouse every once in a while gets disabled in both OSes and the only way to enable it again to manually unplug and plug it. The weird thing is that it's lights are on, but it just doesn't want to work.

It's really annoying having to move the case and unplug the mouse every couple of resets.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: move to superuser

Comment: That sounds like an issue with your current hardware that needs a driver quirk. Try upgrading to the newest kernel, and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to do that if it persists. For now I set Intel xHCI to Auto and it seems to be working fine. But I'll have to see if it gets disabled again or not. thanks for the response.